# Pandasを使った行の比較方法について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

#### やりたいこと

PythonでBook1とBook2のエクセルを比較します。
Book1には無い行を、Book2のヘッダーFlagとしてどの行がないかを記載したいです。

両方のエクセルのキーとなるものはtitleにしています。

Book1のエクセル

```
created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T06:43:17.488Z,日本,2332528852,雨
```

Book2のエクセル

```
created_at,title,messageId,content
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,アメリカ,2332528842,晴れ
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,スペイン,2332528843,,
2022-06-16T06:43:17.488Z,日本,2332528852,雨,
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,カナダ,2332528853,,
```

#### 実現したい結果

Book2にFlagの列を追加して、Book1に行がなければ、Nothingとして記入したいです。

```
created_at,title,messageId,content,Flag
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,アメリカ,2332528842,晴れ,Nothing
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,スペイン,2332528843,,Nothing
2022-06-16T06:43:17.488Z,日本,2332528852,雨,
2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,カナダ,2332528853,,Nothing
```

**現在の結果**
特にエラーなく処理されていますが、NothingのFlagはアメリカだけ記入されます。
他の行もないので、実現したい結果のように記入したいです。

何かクエリで検索する際に間違っていますでしょうか。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけますか。

お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

全体のコード

```
import pandas as pd

#ファイル名
Book1=r"test.xlsx"
Book2=r"test2.xlsx"

#Book1エクセル読み込み
df1 = pd.read_excel(Book1)
#Book2エクセル読み込み
df2 = pd.read_excel(Book2)

#df2のエクセルにヘッダー追加
df2['Flag'] = ""
#df2['コメントフラグ'] = ""
print(df2)

#title keyにして行数を確認
df1_list = df1[['title']].values.tolist()
print(df1_list)

#1行ずつtitleを比較して一致しなければ、Nothingとしてフラグをつける
for curtitle in df1_list:
    wdf = df2.query('(title != @curtitle)')
    #if len(wdf) <= 0: continue
    df2.at[wdf.index[0], 'Flag'] = "Nothing"

#結果をxlsxとして書き出し
df2.to_excel(Book2, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Google Translate, so it might be unnatural.
より良いPandas関数があるようですが、原始的な方法で作成しました。

```
#1行ずつtitleを比較して一致しなければ、Nothingとしてフラグをつける
for curtitle in df1_list:
    wdf = df2.query('(title != @curtitle)')
    for index in wdf.index.values:
        df2.at[index, 'Flag'] = "Nothing"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法で問題なくできました。for分を使うんですね

Answer (score 1):

別の方法

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import io
   ...: 
   ...: csv1, csv2 = '''
   ...: created_at,title,messageId,content
   ...: 2022-06-16T06:43:17.488Z,日本,2332528852,雨
   ...: ''', '''
   ...: created_at,title,messageId,content
   ...: 2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,アメリカ,2332528842,晴れ
   ...: 2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,スペイン,2332528843,
   ...: 2022-06-16T06:43:17.488Z,日本,2332528852,雨
   ...: 2022-06-16T02:28:37.323Z,カナダ,2332528853,
   ...: '''
   ...: df1, df2 = [pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(f.strip()), parse_dates=['created_at'])for f in (csv1, csv2)]
   ...: 

In [2]: df1
Out[2]: 
                        created_at title   messageId content
0 2022-06-16 06:43:17.488000+00:00    日本  2332528852       雨

In [3]: df2
Out[3]: 
                        created_at title   messageId content
0 2022-06-16 02:28:37.323000+00:00  アメリカ  2332528842      晴れ
1 2022-06-16 02:28:37.323000+00:00  スペイン  2332528843     NaN
2 2022-06-16 06:43:17.488000+00:00    日本  2332528852       雨
3 2022-06-16 02:28:37.323000+00:00   カナダ  2332528853     NaN

In [4]: df2['title'].isin('日本')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

In [5]: df2['title'].isin(['日本'])
Out[5]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: title, dtype: bool

In [6]: df2['title'].isin(['日本', 'スペイン'])
Out[6]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: title, dtype: bool

In [7]: df2['title'].isin(df1['title'])
Out[7]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: title, dtype: bool
```

ということで

```py
df2['Flag'] = 'Nothing'
df2.loc[df2['title'].isin(df1['title']), 'Flag'] = ''
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの方法も参考させていただきます。